# how to save data and show it even after closing the app in flutter

Tags: android, flutter, error-handling, save, textfield

```
    class SimpleDialog extends StatelessWidget {
      final GlobalKey<FormState> _formKey = GlobalKey<FormState>();
      final TextEditingController _textEditingController =
          TextEditingController();
     String? baseurl; 
      @override
      Widget build(BuildContext context) {
        return AlertDialog(
          title: Text('Base URL'),
          content: Form(
              key: _formKey,
              child: TextFormField(
                keyboardType: TextInputType.multiline,
                maxLines: null,
                controller: _textEditingController,
                decoration: InputDecoration(
                  hintText: "Please Enter Base Url",
                  border:
                      OutlineInputBorder(borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(15)),
                ),
                validator: (value) {
                  // return value!.isNotEmpty ? null : "Enter Base Url";
                  return Uri.parse(value.toString()).host == ''
                      ? "Enter Base Url"
                      : null;
                },
              )),
          actions: <Widget>[
            Center(
              child: InkWell(
                onTap: () {
                  if (_formKey.currentState!.validate()) {
                    baseurl = _textEditingController.text.toString().trim();
                    checkBaseUrl(baseurl, context);
    
                    print('baseurl=====base------$baseurl');
                  }
                },
                child: Container(
                  width: 100,
                  height: 40,
                  padding: EdgeInsets.all(12.0),
                  decoration: BoxDecoration(
                    color: Colors.blue,
                    borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(20.0),
                  ),
                  child: Text(
                    "Connect",
                    textAlign: TextAlign.center,
                    style: TextStyle(color: Colors.white),
                  ),
                ),
              ),
            )
          ],
        );
      }
    
      Future<void> checkBaseUrl(String baseurl, context) async {
        Response response;
        try {
          response = await http.get(Uri.parse(baseurl));
          print(await response);
          if (response.statusCode == 200) {
            var snackBar = SnackBar(content: Text('Connected Successfully'));
            ScaffoldMessenger.of(context).showSnackBar(snackBar);
            var name = await baseurl;
            await Prefs().seturlBase(name);
            print(await '---pred---prefp---$name');
            baseurl = await Prefs().geturlBase().toString();
            Navigator.of(context).pop();
          } else {
            var snackBar = SnackBar(content: Text('Connection failed'));
            ScaffoldMessenger.of(context).showSnackBar(snackBar);
            Navigator.of(context).pop();
          }
        } catch (e) {
          var snackBar = SnackBar(content: Text('Connection failed'));
          ScaffoldMessenger.of(context).showSnackBar(snackBar);
          Navigator.of(context).pop();
        }

Class Prefs:
  Future<void> seturlBase(String urlBase) async {
    SharedPreferences prefs = await SharedPreferences.getInstance();
    prefs.setString(this.urlBase, urlBase);
  }
 Future<String> geturlBase() async {
    SharedPreferences prefs = await SharedPreferences.getInstance();
    String urlBase;
    urlBase = await prefs.getString(this.urlBase) ?? '';
    return urlBase;
  }
```

[image]

Check out the image, I need to save the URL as an input. After closing the app the URL should save and when users again open their app URL should be there for easy going.
How to achieve it, I used shared preferences.
.....................................................Thank you...........................

Answer (score 0):

firt create a `const` for your *`base url`*

```
const String keyBaseUrl = 'baseUrl'
```

you can save it like this.

```dart
final SharedPreferences sharedPrefs = await SharedPreferences.getInstance();
sharedPrefs.setString(keyBaseUrl, baseurl);
```

and you can get it like this.

```dart
SharedPreferences prefs = await SharedPreferences.getInstance();
String? baseurl = prefs.getString(keyBaseUrl);
```